# How can I set AppENgine (Java) urlfetch deadline using java.net API

Tags: java, google-app-engine

I can set the urlfetch deadline by using the appengine urlfetch API [1], but is there a way of doing it using java.net?

[1] http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/javadoc/com/google/appengine/api/urlfetch/FetchOptions.html#setDeadline(java.lang.Double)

Comment: The reason is that I want my library to work on and off app engine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use URLConnection [setConnectTimeout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/URLConnection.html#setConnectTimeout%28int%29) and [setReadTimeout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/URLConnection.html#setReadTimeout%28int%29) methods.

Comment: Any idea of the maximum value?

Comment: Normal timeout is 5s. I believe you can extend it to 10s.

Comment: maximum is 60s in a regular request, and 10m in the tasks/cron, default is 5s.